# wchar/char variables

Tags: c++, windows, char, wchar

I am working in two different versions of c++ `(builder 2009 and XE1)`.
In both I need to use the same file `f.cpp`, which contains function `LoadLibrary("path")`.
`Builder 2009` requires path of type `char` and `XE1` - `wchar`, so this invokes error.

Is there some way to use "LoadLibrary()" with both char&wchar?

tanks.

Comment: The `TCHAR` macros are normally sufficient

Answer (score 3):

Use the type TCHAR that is either wchar or char depending on the macro `_UNICODE`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the preprocessor for this, using the `#if defined` functionality to decide which to use:

```
#if defined(__SOME_SPECIAL_DEFINE_FOR_ONE_COMPILER__)
LoadLibrary("path");
#elif defined(__SOME_OTHER_SPECIAL_DEFINE_FOR_OTHER_COMPILER__)
LoadLibrary(L"path");
#else
# error unknown compiler
#endif
```